# Forms based on selection in django admin

Tags: django, admin

I have a need for the following situation but am struggling to find an answer so if you could provide some pointers, I'd be appreciative:

I have model called SomeObject, PropertyBase, PropertyOne, PropertyTwo

```
class PropertyBase(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(....)


    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class PropertyOne(PropertyBase):
    # properties here particular to the One subclass of PropertyBase

class PropertyTwo(PropertyBase):
    # properties here particular to the Two subclass of PropertyBase

class SomeObject(models.Model):
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    property_base = models.ManyToManyField(PropertyBase)
```

I want the user of my Django Admin to be able to create  SomeObject instances but be able to select what type of property from a list (these will list the subclasses of PropertyBase - i.e. PropertyOne, PropertyTwo etc.).   Then, I want the user to see the correct admin.ModelAdmin based on that selection.

What's the best way about doing this?

E.g.   User creates a new SomeObject instance.  In the admin for this class, they select 'PropertyTwo' from a list.  Then the admin shows the correct admin form for all the properties on my PropertyTwo instance and saves everything to the database appropriately.   I would rather not have an intermediate admin page, although I don't mind a refresh based on the selection.  Do I have to do something with Ajax (with which I'm unfamiliar)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried the code you have so far?  I'm a bit dubious that a `ManyToManyField` to an abstract base model will even work

Comment: It doesn't really have to be an abstract Base class.  It is more the principal that users make a selection and then I want the firm displayed for that selection.  I know I could do it with an intermediate form but I would prefer not to.